# How to get detailed error message using docker-compose up? I can only see "command returned non-zero code"

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my docker-container on linux. During build I'm encountering an error after running this command:

> sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build

docker-compose shows this message:

```
Step 10/19 : RUN dotnet restore "test/test.csproj"
 ---> Running in ea65364853f3
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
ERROR: Service 'test' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "test/test.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is there any way I can see detailed error message?

Comment: You already got the detailed error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring during the build process. You should see the same results when you run `docker-compose build`.

This error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

means that Docker tried to run the `dotnet` executable inside the container, but it couldn't start because the `dotnet` binary in the image is incompatible with the environment in the container. Perhaps it is compiled for a different architecture, or something like that? If you show the rest of your build process (steps 1-9) we can probably spot the problem for you.

Comment: Yes, indeed, later I've discovered that there was a problem with architecture compatibility. Your answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Because `RUN` commands are said to work like this:
get an image, create a container ContainerA, run your command in this container, and generate a new image ImageB. delete ContainerA, create ContainerB...
Now it quits at one RUN, so it must leave a containerX behind. Therefore, you can see log like this:

```
docker build -t <yourname>:<tag>
```

> > quit on error

```
docker logs <yourname>
```

> > here is your detailed error log.

Comment: The `docker logs` command only deals with container logs, not build or image logs.